# Perl/Sed command to replace same pattern multiple times

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, ubuntu-16.04

I need to set `disable=no` in `/etc/xinetd.d/chargen` using commands like perl or sed.

`/etc/xinetd.d/chargen` content is:

```
# description: An xinetd internal service which generate characters.  The
# xinetd internal service which continuously generates characters until the
# connection is dropped.  The characters look something like this:
# !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg
# This is the tcp version. 
service chargen
{
        disable         = yes
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = chargen-stream
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        user            = root
        wait            = no 
}

# This is the udp version. 
service chargen
{
        disable         = yes
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = chargen-dgram
        socket_type     = dgram
        protocol        = udp
        user            = root
        wait            = yes 
}
```

I have used perl command

```
perl -0777 -pe 's|(service chargen[^\^]+)disable\s+=\syes|\1disable=no|' /etc/xinetd.d/chargen
```

but it is replacing at only one place.

```
# description: An xinetd internal service which generate characters.  The
# xinetd internal service which continuously generates characters until the
# connection is dropped.  The characters look something like this:
# !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg
# This is the tcp version.
service chargen
{
        disable         = yes
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = chargen-stream
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        user            = root
        wait            = no
}

# This is the udp version.
service chargen
{
        disable=no
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = chargen-dgram
        socket_type     = dgram
        protocol        = udp
        user            = root
        wait            = yes
}
```

what is the proper command to make it work in both places?

**NOTE**: I could have replaced `disable         = yes` with `disable         = no` without matching `service chargen` but I need to use same sed/perl command to replace in `/etc/xinetd.conf` which will have other services too.

**UPDATE** As Jonathan highlighted in his comment, disable can be at any position inside the flower bracket.

Comment: You have a typo in your replacement text `disbale` instead of `disable`.

Comment: Change `[^\^]+` to `.*?` and add `sg` flags after the second `|`. And replace `\1` with `$1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`, you can use:

```
sed -e '/^service chargen/,/^}/ { /disable *= yes/ s/yes/no/; }'
```

The first part searches for ranges of lines from one starting `service chargen` to the first line afterwards that starts with `}`; within that range, it looks for lines containing `disable = yes` with arbitrary numbers of spaces between `disable` and the `= yes`, and changes the `yes` to `no`.  If necessary, you can make the regexes fussier (no trailing white space; don't edit `service chargen2018` blocks, demand the `}` have no trailing blanks, etc.) but it probably isn't necessary.

You can often do in-place editing, but beware of differences between systems in the semantics of how you do that.  (BSD and macOS require `-i ''`; GNU only requires `-i`; both accept `-i.bak` and it means the same in both — but you have a backup file to cleanup.)

Comment: As currently written, the Perl solution only works if the `disable` line is the first in the `service chargen` description.  It could be modified to handle `disable` lines as other than the first; there's no modification needed to the `sed` script for that. It may not be a problem worth worrying about.

Comment: Yes, disable can be at any position inside the flower bracket. thanks for highlighting it.

Comment: `sed -E '/^service chargen/,/^}/s/(disable *= *)yes/\1no/'` might be a bit shorter.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `perl` command:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(?m)^service chargen\s*\{[^}]*disable\s*=\s*\Kyes/no/g' file
```

```
# description: An xinetd internal service which generate characters.  The
# xinetd internal service which continuously generates characters until the
# connection is dropped.  The characters look something like this:
# !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg
# This is the tcp version.
service chargen
{
        disable         = no
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = chargen-stream
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        user            = root
        wait            = no
}

# This is the udp version.
service chargen
{
        disable         = no
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = chargen-dgram
        socket_type     = dgram
        protocol        = udp
        user            = root
        wait            = yes
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JVCD7o/2)

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Sorry I had forgotten to mention that disable can be at any position inside the flower bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Awk ok?:

```
$ awk '/service chargen/,/}/{if(/disable/)sub(/yes/,"no")}1' file
...
        disable         = no
...
        disable         = no
...
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '                          # well, awk
/service chargen/,/}/ {          # between service chargen {...}
    if(/disable/)                # if disable found
        sub(/yes/,"no")          # replace yes with no
}1' file                         # output
```

Feel free to tune the regex (`/disable/`) to your liking (for example `/^ *disable *=/`).

Comment: Hi James, I want to match ```service chrgen``` too. anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Updated with the `service chrgen{...}`.